# Right way to implement pandas.read_sql with ClickHouse

Tags: pandas, clickhouse

Trying to implement [**pandas.read_sql**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html#pandas.read_sql) function.

I created a **clickhouse** table and filled it:

```
create table regions
(
    date DateTime Default now(),
    region String
)
    engine = MergeTree()
        PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(date)
        ORDER BY tuple()
        SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192;

insert into regions (region) values ('Asia'), ('Europe')
```

Then python code:

```
import pandas as pd 
from sqlalchemy import create_engine


uri = 'clickhouse://default:@localhost/default'
engine = create_engine(uri)
query = 'select * from regions'
pd.read_sql(query, engine)
```

As the result I expected to get a dataframe with columns **date** and **region** but all I get is empty dataframe:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [2021-01-08 09:24:33, Asia]
Index: []
```

UPD. It occured that defining **clickhouse+native** solves the problem.

Can it be solved without **+native**?

Comment: https://github.com/xzkostyan/clickhouse-sqlalchemy/issues/10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is encient issue https://github.com/xzkostyan/clickhouse-sqlalchemy/issues/10. Also there is a hint which assumes to add **FORMAT TabSeparatedWithNamesAndTypes** at the end of a query. So the init query will be look like this:

```
select * 
from regions 
FORMAT TabSeparatedWithNamesAndTypes
```